# Does dependency injection try to supply a value for c'tor parameters with a default value

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

We have lots of unit tests which were written when the constructor signature for `Foo` was

```
Foo(Bar bar)
```

Now we want to extend the constructor to `Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz)`, but that will mean modifying all those unit tests...

... Unless we supply a default value `Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz = default)`

I know that dependency injection requires a default for things it *cannot* construct, but what will it do if it *can* construct a Baz, and the parameter has a default value?

Comment: did you already tried ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran an experiment and the answer is "yes".  If dependency injection can construct a `Baz`, then that is what the constructor will receive, *not* the default.